# how to get result of a table condition on having all of value of where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three table A and B and C that primary key of A exists in B and primary key of C exists in B:
Table A:

```
id
---
1
2
3
4
```

Table B:

```
id   A_id     code      c_id  
-----------------------------
1     1        20        1
2     1        30        1
3     1        40        3
4     2        20        2
5     3        30        3
6     4        40        2
7     4        30        2
8     1        20        3
9     4        30        4
```

Table C:

```
 id   name
    ---------
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

I have a query that it has a where clause consist of value of column code of B and return records of A
I want to get records of A that those have total code of where clause instead of some of it. 
for example:

```
SELECT ID FROM A a INNER JOIN B b
            ON a.id = b.A_id
    where b.code in(20, 30, 40);
```

My expectancy is only below result of A:

```
id
----
1
```

Because that top result("1") only has all of value of code(20, 30, 40)
and another example ca be:

```
SELECT ID FROM A a INNER JOIN B b
            ON a.id = b.A_id
    where b.code in(30, 40);
```

My expectancy is:

```
id
----
4
```

Comment: you are not  using table `C` anywhere ... or am I missing something? Also what do you mean by *'where clause has dynamic value'*? will it be a parameter of some kind or do you mean that you just manually will add other values to the in clause?

Answer (score 2):

I will use `listagg` to concat all codes into one string (`agregated_codes`) , and then check for matches (final select statement). But before that, I'll collect only distinct records from `Bdata` (`distinct_data`)

```
with
Adata as (
select 1 id from dual union all
select 2 id from dual union all
select 3 id from dual union all
select 4 id from dual 
),
 Bdata as (
select 1 id,     1 a_id,        20 code,        1 c_id from dual union all
select 2 id,     1 a_id,        30 code,        1 c_id from dual union all
select 3 id,     1 a_id,        40 code,        3 c_id from dual union all
select 4 id,     2 a_id,        20 code,        2 c_id from dual union all
select 5 id,     3 a_id,        30 code,        3 c_id from dual union all
select 6 id,     4 a_id,        40 code,        2 c_id from dual union all
select 7 id,     4 a_id,        30 code,        2 c_id from dual union all
select 8 id,     1 a_id,        20 code,        3 c_id from dual union all
select 9 id,     4 a_id,        30 code,        4 c_id from dual
),
distinct_data as
(
select distinct a_id,code from Bdata 
),
agregated_codes as 
(
select a_id, listagg(code,',') within group (order by a_id) codes    
from distinct_data  group by a_id 
)
select * from Adata where id in ( select a_id from agregated_codes where codes in ('20,30,40'))
```

**Results:**

for `'20,30,40'` result is `1`

for `'30,40'`    result is `4`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
Select A.Id
from A a INNER JOIN B b
        ON a.id = b.A_id
where b.code in(20, 30, 40)
group by A.Id
having count(A.Id) = 3
```

Here the last line `count(A.Id) = 3` will make sure that it will return Id when it meets all the code specified in the `IN` clause.

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (A.Id) 
FROM A a INNER JOIN B b
            ON a.id = b.A_id
WHERE A.Id In (select A_id from user where code = 20) 
    And A.Id In (select A_id from user where code = 30)  
    And A.Id In (select A_id from user where code = 40) ;
```

Comment: no in fact table B have duplicate value then count(A.id) wont be correct

Comment: count(A.Id) of Your answer is 4 no 3

Comment: @rezaramezanimatin:- Updated my answer. Could you please check now!

Comment: It is not suitable answer because of that my where clause is dynamic value

Comment: (select A_id from user where code = 20) <br />
    A.Id In (select A_id from user where code = 30)  <br />
    A.Id In (select A_id from user where code = 40)  is static

Comment: No no the where clause is dynamic value in fact i can be 20,30,40 and can be 20, 30 and can be 20,30,40,50,60,50,80,90,,...

Comment: @rezaramezanimatin:- `select
    id
from
    A a
where
    exists
    (select 1 from B b where b.id = a.id and b.code in(20, 30, 40))`

Comment: please would you complete query select id from A a where exists (select 1 from B b where b.id = a.id and b.code in(20, 30, 40))

Answer (score 0):

Use exists clause.

To select only those records that have code values 20,30 and 40.

```
select distinct a_id from B outB
where exists (select code from B  where outB.a_id = a_id and code =20)
and exists (select * from B where outB.a_id = a_id and code =30)
and exists (select * from B where outB.a_id = a_id and code =40);
```

To select only those records that have code values 30 and 40.

```
select distinct a_id from B outB
where not exists (select * from B where outB.a_id = a_id and code =20)
and exists (select * from B where outB.a_id = a_id and code =30)
and exists (select * from B where outB.a_id = a_id and code =40);
```

Comment: No no the where clause is dynamic value in fact i can be 20,30,40 and can be 20, 30 and can be 20,30,40,50,60,50,80,90,,...

Comment: This is not a good solution but you can use not exists clause for all codes that you don't want and exists clause for the codes you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect all `B.code` values in single column for each `B.A_id` value, and then just compare this column with  condition string like `'10,20,30'`.

```
SELECT t.A_id 
  FROM ( SELECT t_B.A_id, LISTAGG(t_B.code, ',')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t_B.code) AS all_codes FROM (SELECT DISTINCT B.A_id, B.code FROM B) t_B  GROUP BY t_B.A_id) t
 WHERE t.all_codes LIKE '30,40'
```

I have corrected my code, added `DISTINCT`.

Comment: This will not work, for `'30,40'` ... and generally will have an issue with repeating codes.

Comment: @Plirkee Thank you, I have found my mistake and have added `DISTINCT`